# What is this 4x4 board with black and white sided, numbered pegs?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]

I found this little boardgame but cannot figure out what it is. Hopefully you can help me?

Comment: Can you describe how the pegs are numbered? Does each peg have the same number on both ends, and how many of each number are there?

Answer (score 4):

It's a "My First Sudoku / Child Sudoku" puzzle (a 4-number version of the usual 9-number pencil puzzle).

See for example this [Etsy listing](https://www.etsy.com/listing/455090042/wooden-toy-sudoku-kid-wooden-the-organic?gpla=1&gao=1&&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping_us_d-toys_and_games-games_and_puzzles-other&utm_custom1=79d39dee-c526-4904-9f13-5fa6371a5b98&utm_content=go_304504595_49684139715_233289809178_pla-314262775107_c__455090042&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI9OT8ro3_4AIVCluGCh1nXgXOEAQYASABEgKPxPD_BwE).

Comment: Is there a reason for the different coloration of pegs?  Or is it just aesthetic?

Comment: You use one color to fill in the given/starting numbers of a puzzle. Then you fill in your solution with the other color. That way you know which pegs you can't change if you make a mistake and need to backtrack / change numbers.